# Codeigniter: Parsing value from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to parsing value from controller to view? I always got **Undefined variable** error in view page when I call book_title and book_category value from controller. Can someone help me? Thanks.

controller (Book.php):

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('md_book');
}

public function book_controller(){
        $login_type = $this->session->userdata('login_type');
        $page_data['login_type']      = $login_type;
        $page_data['page_name']       = 'book';
        $page_data['page_title']      = 'Book';
        $page_data['page_function']   = __FUNCTION__;
        $page_data['page_breadcrumb'] = generate_breadcrumb(array('Book'));

        $data['book_title']     = $this->input->post('book_title');
        $data['book_category']  = $this->input->post('book_category');

        $this->md_book->addBook($data);

        $this->load->view('index', $page_data);
}
```

model (md_book.php) :

```
function addBook($data){
    $this->db->insert('tb_books', $data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ? $this->db->insert_id() : FALSE;
}
```

view (book.php)

```
 <div class="form-group form-float">
      <p>Book Title</b></p>
      <div class="form-line">
           <input type="text" name="book_title" class="form-control" size="30" required>
      </div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group form-float">
      <p>Book Category</b></p>
      <div class="form-line">
           <input type="text" name="book_category" class="form-control" size="30" required>
      </div>
</div>

**//I got error on this code
<div class="body">
     Book Title    : <?php echo $book_title;?>
     Book Category : <?php echo $book_category;?>
</div>**
```

Comment: Hello, It seems to me that you have loaded the view index in the controller, but from what I read your view is called "book.php" so you just need to correct in the controller "$this->load->view('index', $page_data);" with "$this->load->view('book', $page_data);".

Comment: there are two arrays you have assigned values in controller one is $data and another in $page_data
but you have passed only $page_data in load->view

$this->load->view('index', $page_data);

Instead of 

$data['book_title']     = $this->input->post('book_title');
 $data['book_category']  = $this->input->post('book_category');

use

$page_data['book_title']     = $this->input->post('book_title');
$page_data['book_category']  = $this->input->post('book_category');

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    public function book_controller(){
        $login_type = $this->session->userdata('login_type');
        $page_data['login_type']      = $login_type;
        $page_data['page_name']       = 'book';
        $page_data['page_title']      = 'Book';
        $page_data['page_function']   = __FUNCTION__;
        $page_data['page_breadcrumb'] = generate_breadcrumb(array('Book'));
        $page_data['book_title']     = $this->input->post('book_title');
        $page_data['book_category']  = $this->input->post('book_category');   
        $this->md_book->addBook();
        $this->load->view('index', $page_data);
}
```

Edit the model as

```
function addBook(){
  $data = array('book_title'=>$this->input->post('book_title'),'book_category'=>$this->input->post('book_category'))
    $this->db->insert('tb_books', $data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ? $this->db->insert_id() : FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are loading the wrong view:

```
    $this->load->view('index', $page_data);
```

You should call the correct view, then you will be able to correctly output `$book_title` & `$book_categor`. Try this (considering thqt book is your correct view) it might correct your error:

```
    $this->load->view('book', $page_data);
```

Refer to this user guide to learn more about views in [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Comment: It's not an answer. It seems to be a comment.